# Is there a name for a collection of open sets where arbitrary intersections are open?

Tags: general-topology, definition

Let $\mathcal{U} = \{U_i\}_{i\in I} $ be a collection of open sets with the property that the set $\bigcap_{i\in J} U_i $ is open for all subsets $J$ of $I$.

Is there a name for such collections of open sets?

Both locally finite collections and point-finite collections have this property, but these notions are too strong (just think of infinite discrete spaces).

Comment: A topological space in which _every_ collection of open sets has this property is called an Alexandrov space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Such collections have been called *interior preserving*, as in the definition of *orthocompact space* found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthocompact_space). An older and less descriptive term is *Q-collection*, as in [this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1979-077-03/S0002-9939-1979-0545602-6/home.html).

Comment: Excellent! On the odd chance that somebody comes along with a better answer, I'll wait a little before accepting.

Comment: @Roar: No problem: someone may have come up with a better name since I worked with them.